# What's the equivalent of `core-animated-pages-transition-prepare` in `neon-animated-pages`

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

What's the equivalent of `core-animated-pages-transition-prepare` in `<neon-animated-pages>`?

Specifically I need to trigger `measureHeaderHeight` on my `<paper-scroll-header-panel>` before it's actually shown, but after it is 'visible' in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be the only one 'official' event - neon-animation-finish, but  it's fired when the page is shown. And all the pages managed by neon-animated-pages stay in DOM, just transformed out of screen (with  'translateX(-100%)).

You also may try to override some of the internal methods like _configureAnimationEffects or _runAnimationEffects.